# How to make a new line in list?

Tags: python, list

I want to make a new line when making list.

I have tried this code in order to make a chart with list.

```
[[[] for i in range(3)] for i in range(4)]

[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]
```

But what I want to print out is

```
[[[], [], []], 
[[], [], []], 
[[], [], []], 
[[], [], []]]
```

and I have no idea how to add '\n' in this code..
THANK YOU:)

Answer (score 7):

Use `pprint`:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([[[] for i in range(3)] for i in range(4)], width=30)
[[[], [], []],
 [[], [], []],
 [[], [], []],
 [[], [], []]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
a = [[[] for i in range(3)] for i in range(4)]
sep = ',\n'
print(f"[{sep.join(str(e) for e in a)}]")
```

output:

```
[[[], [], []],
[[], [], []],
[[], [], []],
[[], [], []]]
```